# Guardar varios registro a partir de un rango de fechas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo 2 datepicker (Fecha inicial y Fecha final), Si la Fecha inicial es diferente a la fecha final colocada en los datepicker's, como hago para crear en la base de datos un registro para cada dia dentro del rango de fechas selecionadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Los datos que quieres guardar cuales son?

Comment: los campos en mi BD son: nombre, fecha (un registro por cada fecha si el datepicker tiene fechas distintas) Ejemplo: 12/10/18 - 14/10/18, eso me crearia 3 registros con las fechas 12, 13, 14 que corresponden al mismo usuario

Comment: ¿Y los datos los envias por el formulario donde tienes las fechas?

Comment: @Oswuell SI los datos los envio por formulario

Comment: Pero no veo que en el formulario los muestres..

Comment: Lo coloque abajo, en una respuesta

Comment: Solo veo que tienes 3 campos las fechas y una nota ¿?

Comment: Son esos los campos que quiero guardar en la base de datos pero por cada fecha en el rango de fecha entre el datepicker1 y el datepicker2 crear un registro

Comment: No entiendo amigo lo que quieres hacer, trata de organizar mejor la pregunta y cual es el resultado que esperas.

Comment: Tengo un formulario que consta de 3 campos: (Fecha inicio, Fecha Fin, Nota), si los campos 'Fecha inicio' y 'Fecha fin' son iguales (12/10/18 - 12/1018) solo se almacena un registro, pero sin son diferentes (12/10/18 - 15/10/18) se almacena 1 registro por cada dia dentro del rango de esas fechas (serian 4 registros), con la misma nota pero con fecha distintas.

Comment: Curiosidad. ¿Porque quieres hacer eso?

Comment: Requerimientos del cliente, que recomiendas tu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es el formulario donde se muestran los datepickers
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]